# Hide textview in Listview row based on condition

Tags: android, listview

I have a code here that displays data in custom listview from my database

```
List<Map<String, String>> data1 = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
            while (data.moveToNext()) {
                Map<String, String> datum = new HashMap<String, String>(5);
                datum.put("Customer Name", data.getString(0));
                datum.put("Address", data.getString(1));
                datum.put("Remarks", data.getString(2));
                datum.put("Date", data.getString(3));
                datum.put("Code", data.getString(4));
                data1.add(datum);
            }
            adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getActivity(), data1,
                    R.layout.listview_plan,
                    new String[]{"Customer Name", "Address", "Remarks", "Date", "Code"},
                    new int[]{R.id.list_name,
                            R.id.list_address,
                            R.id.list_remarks,
                            R.id.list_date, R.id.list_code});

            listView.setAdapter(adapter);
            count.setText("" + listView.getAdapter().getCount());
```

My question is during population I want to add some condition like hiding a textview. How can I do that?

sample

```
ListView.Populate{
   if (data.getString(3)) == null) {
      //Hide the label on that row
   }

}
```

My target is to hide a specific textview in listview

Comment: write the condition on the adapter

Comment: like how? dont know where to start

Comment: get the count of the adapter. if it is more than 0 you can hide your 
`if (adapter.getCount() > 0) {
// hide textview
} else {
  //show textview
}`

Comment: @myownemail which type of condition you want, can you please elaborate your question

Comment: actually i will hide specific textview inside the listview (edited post)

Comment: You need custom adapter with model class list

Comment: @RajshreeTiwari my target is if some data on that adapter has no value I want to hide its textview. dont want to include in rendering

Comment: @myownemail is your list is static?

Comment: @RajshreeTiwari you mean the data inside it? it populates by a database

Comment: what would be the best approach for this?

Comment: @myownemail just need clearification , when you are getting data from databse then why you are showing hardcoded value :-   adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getActivity(), data1,
                    R.layout.listview_plan,
                    new String[]{"Customer Name", "Address", "Remarks", "Date", "Code"},
                    new int[]{R.id.list_name,
                            R.id.list_address,
                            R.id.list_remarks,
                            R.id.list_date, R.id.list_code});

Comment: @RajshreeTiwari because it is a custom listview

Comment: @myownemail you are saying that you are displaying the data from database, then why you are entering values like that?

Comment: is it wrong also? i didnt expect that. what are the proper ways to do that? maybe we will discuss that on seperate post

Comment: In your Adapter when creating the view and setting the values to the text views make the condition and hide your textView there text.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)